# Add TFS2013 check-in policy - checkbox

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Hi I am looking to add a checkbox to the TFS check-in page in Visual Studio, that a developer has to tick before being able to do a check-in.

This is to act as a reminder for them, so they read the reminder and tick the box to say they have done it.

Is this possible with custom TFS2013 policies? And are there resources/tutorials which explain how this could be done?

Comment: If there are things a developer has to do before checkin then would this better be captured as a work item? You can then setup a checkin policy that requires a work item that satisfies certain criteria using the `Work Item Query Policy` in the [TFS Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f)

Answer (score 1):

For this I would recommend you use a basic checkin note.  They will as to put in a note they they have done whatever you want before they can checkin.  This will be a hard stop.  Like pero was saying in the comment, a work item is also a good solution and a better plan long term. Then you can just turn on checkin policy and force them to pick an item before checkin.  This can be overridden, while checkin notes cannot.